# apache/php configuration troubles

Tags: apache, freebsd, php

I think I might have touched something wrong in my server configuration (tinkered with a LOT of things to get some weird software running) and now phpMyAdmin is acting up.

First it gave me that "Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error." (chrome specific), then I set zlib.output_compression = Off in php.ini (rebooted apache) and how the css file is not working.

I know phpmyadmin is just the symptom here, if anyone has a clue about what is going on, I'd be eternally grateful.

If you need any configuration file simply ask and I'll post/pastebin it (I'm on a FreeBSD server btw.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out mod_suphp was creating conflicts preventing any setting of Content-types via header(); I deactivated it in httpd.conf and now everything works perfectly.